# Is it possible install a drain flange without breaking up the concrete around the roughed-in pipe?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, basement

My house was built with rough-in plumbing in the basement cement floor as are many houses in the past 25 years.  The rough-in plumbing includes a 4" PVC pipe in the floor for a toilet and a 2" PVC pipe for a shower or bathtub.

I am planning to install a walk-in shower with a curb that is 15 inches from the center-line of the toilet per our county code.

The 2" PVC rough-in pipe is at one end of the rectangular shower floor area and protrudes up out of the cement about 2 inches and is capped.

I would like to install a mortar type shower floor base with a drain with a flange.  However the flange would be above the concrete floor probably about 3 inches.  I have a liner as well to waterproof the base.

Is it possible install the drain with flange without breaking up cement around the 2 inch pipe?

What about the toilet?  Possible to install without breaking up the concrete?  It would seem the builders installed the pipes so they can be used as-is.  I believe all the homes in my area were built with rough-ins similar to ours around year 2005.

Comment: What _about_ the toilet? The flange would normally be installed directly into that 4" pipe as an internal fitment. Is there some reason that won't work? As to the shower, why would you raise the drain 3"? I can see the curb being raised, and the outer slope of the floor, but the drain should remain as low as possible. You don't need an elevated shower.

Comment: Regarding the toilet, I don't know why it wouldn't work. I do have a plumber who will probably install that but I'm trying to do as much of the work that I can myself such as the shower install. I agree, I want the drain as low as possible, but does that mean I have to jack hammer up the floor to do that? I would have thought the rough-in pipes would have been installed by the builder such that that isn't required, but I may be wrong on that.

Comment: You haven't made it clear what the problem with the shower pipe is. Shower drains are designed to fit _into_ a 2" pipe cut to the right protrusion height. Are you saying that it's in the wrong location? That's common. The builder can't know what your plans will be in the future, so they guess based on common outcomes. If you have to cut out (not jackhammer) some concrete, so be it. It's not a terribly difficult job. Rent a diamond saw.